# How can I combine two views into one to condense my data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one with names of players and the # of games won and one with names of players and the # of games lost. I'd like to combine them to show the names of players, # games won and # of games lost into one table

Also would like to be able to show # of games played by adding games won to games lost

table1

| name | g_won |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2 |
| b | 4 |

table2

| name | g_lost |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2 |
| c | 5 |

would like the new table to return:

| name | g_won | g_lost | g_played |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| b | 4 | 0 | 4 |
| c | 0 | 5 | 5 |

Comment: Why do you have two tables in the first place? A single table with a won and lost column would make more sense surely.

Comment: `UNION` them into expanded structure and then aggregate.

Comment: Yeah will require a JOIN UNION but trying to figure out if its an INNER, OUTER, LEFT,RIGHT etc is probably holding you back?)  Also .. do these tables have primary keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a `UNION` operation and then select the `SUM` for each `g_won` and `g_lost`:

```
SELECT name,
       SUM(g_won)        AS g_won,
       SUM(g_lost)       AS g_lost, 
       SUM(g_won+g_lost) AS g_played
FROM (SELECT name,
             g_won,
             0 AS g_lost
      FROM table1
      UNION
      SELECT name,
             0 AS g_won,
             g_lost
      FROM table2            ) tab 
GROUP BY name
```

Try it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8g5MZvjLHH9E1hydHASiUG/2).

Answer (score 0):

You could obtain your desired result by unioning a left or right outer-join of each table and then aggregating. You could create this as a *view* to reference it as another table.

```
select name, 
    Sum(g_won) g_won, Sum(g_lost) g_lost, 
    Sum(g_won) + Sum(g_lost) g_played
from (
    select t1.name, g_won, 0 g_lost
    from t1
    left join t2 on t2.name=t1.name
    union
    select t2.name, 0 g_won, g_lost
    from t2
    left join t1 on t2.name=t1.name
)t
group by name;
```

See [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=bb36d908f0c75a085a1061d3bf44ca0e)